# Android, Tabs' content overlapping

Tags: android, tabs

I'm trying to set up tabs for my app. But, after I'm done with the UI, tapping on the tabs causes the buttons and labels to appear at the same time. Example, Tab1 shows one button. When I tap on Tab2, the buttons appears on Tab2.

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="254dp"
                android:layout_height="25dp" >
            </TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabPower"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/hear" />

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/sb"
                        android:layout_width="253dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

                    <ToggleButton
                        android:id="@+id/tb"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:text="ToggleButton" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabEq"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="right"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <CheckBox
                            android:id="@+id/enabled"
                            android:layout_width="105dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="fill"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:text="@string/enabled" />

                        <Button
                            android:id="@+id/flat"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="left"
                            android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                            android:layout_weight="0.42"
                            android:text="@string/flat" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bass_booost"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/bass_boost" />

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/bass_boost"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                        android:max="1000"
                        android:progress="0" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.13"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/slider1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.13"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:progress="50"
                        android:secondaryProgress="50" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView3"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.13"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/slider_2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.13"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:progress="50"
                        android:secondaryProgress="50" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView4"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.13"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/slider_3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.13"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:progress="50"
                        android:secondaryProgress="50" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView5"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.13"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/slider_4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.13"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:progress="50"
                        android:secondaryProgress="50" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView6"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="0.13"
                        android:text="TextView" />

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/slider_5"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                        android:layout_weight="0.13"
                        android:max="100"
                        android:progress="50"
                        android:secondaryProgress="50" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my layout file, please kindly let me know if there is something I should be implementing.

Comment: android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"                      remove those line from linear layout

Comment: Is this what you are describing your desired result or your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't phrase my question properly. I don't want my tabs to be overlapping.

Comment: Removing the things you listed doesn't seems to help.

Answer (score 5):

There are probably a few things you can change here to make your layout top notch. First, modify your layout xml, noticing a few things:

1. Android has built in IDs for the elements of tabhost: `@android:id/tabhost`, `@android:id/tabs` , `@android:id/tabcontent`. I'd recommend using those for simplicity's sake;
2. The `FrameLayout` `@android:id/tabcontent` needs an `android:paddingTop` value or the content will show up on top of the tabs. I've chosen 62dp (see http://androidituts.com/android-tab-layout-example/);
3. I've changed the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` you gave to `match_parent` and `match_parent` for the `TabHost` and `match_parent` & `wrap_content` for `TabWidget`because android will give you a nice layout by default;
4. I've removed the `LinearLayout` you included as a child of `TabHost`; there's no need for it;
5. The `fill_parent` value for `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` is deprecated, so I've replaced it with `match_parent`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html, which describes fill_parent:

> The view should be as big as its parent (minus padding). This constant
>   is deprecated starting from API Level 8 and is replaced by
>   match_parent.

Below is the source to the new xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="62dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabPower"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hear" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/sb"
                android:layout_width="253dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <ToggleButton
                android:id="@+id/tb"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="ToggleButton" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabEq"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <CheckBox
                    android:id="@+id/enabled"
                    android:layout_width="105dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="fill"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Enabled" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/flat"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_weight="0.42"
                    android:text="Flat" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bass_booost"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bass Boost" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/bass_boost"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
                android:max="1000"
                android:progress="0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.13"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/slider1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.13"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="50"
                android:secondaryProgress="50" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.13"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/slider_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.13"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="50"
                android:secondaryProgress="50" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView4"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.13"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/slider_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.13"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="50"
                android:secondaryProgress="50" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.13"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/slider_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.13"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="50"
                android:secondaryProgress="50" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.13"
                android:text="TextView" />

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/slider_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.13"
                android:max="100"
                android:progress="50"
                android:secondaryProgress="50" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Next you have to take care of setting up the tabs in your Fragment. The steps are simple:

1. Get a reference to the TabHost using View.findViewById(int id);
2. Call TabHost.setup();
3. Add each tab to the TabHost.

Here's the Fragment code that sets up the Fragment's view:

```
public class FragmentWithTabs extends Fragment {

private TabHost mTabHost;

public FragmentWithTabs(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);

    mTabHost = (TabHost) v.findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_power").setContent(R.id.tabPower).setIndicator("Tab Power"));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_eq").setContent(R.id.tabEq).setIndicator("Tab Eq"));


    return v;
}


}
```

That's it! Here's a screenshot or 2:

[image: This is the power tab]

[image: This is the eq tab]

Comment: +1 , My tabs were overlapping...PaddingTop done the trick :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit the beginning of your XML to this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            </TabWidget>
```

The functionality of hiding/showing the content layouts you should do in your `MainActivity`.